# Беда с высотой картинок на iOS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Друзья, помогите решить проблему с авто высотой картинок для iOS. У меня есть элемент у которого динамичная ширина, т.е. юзер её в ручную масштабирует ползунком. Мне надо, чтоб высота была auto, и картинку не плющило. Для windows и Android у меня проблем не возникает, но вот для iOS устройств, беда просто. Ширина вытягивается почему то и картинку плющит. Задавать высоту статичной не подходит для решения моего вопроса. height: auto !important; уже стоит, не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Если кому поможет данный вопрос, ответ, для картинки задать display: flex; min-height: auto; align-self: flex-start;